# Dropbox value change after button click due to pageload

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use asp dropbox and fill the dropbox from database.but the value of dropbox change when click on button because the when event of button call first pageload code call and in pageload i fill the dropbox from database 
the code is

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        var q = from u in db.tbl_Subject select u;
        Paper_Subject.DataSource=q.ToList();
        Paper_Subject.DataTextField = "Subject_Name";
        Paper_Subject.DataValueField = "Subject_Id";
        Paper_Subject.DataBind();


        for (int i = 0; i <= 12;i++)
        {
            if(i<10)
                Paper_Duration_Hour.Items.Add("0"+i.ToString());
            else
                Paper_Duration_Hour.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= 60; i=i+5)
        {
            if(i<10)
                Paper_Duration_Minute.Items.Add("0"+i.ToString());
            else
                Paper_Duration_Minute.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        }
    }
protected void SaveData()
    {
        int PaperDurationHour;
        int PaperDurationMinute;
        int TeacherId;
        int SubjectId;
        tb.Paper_Name = PaperName.Text;
        if (int.TryParse(Paper_Duration_Hour.Text, out PaperDurationHour))
        {
            tb.Paper_Time_Hours = PaperDurationHour;
        }
        if (int.TryParse(Paper_Duration_Minute.Text, out PaperDurationMinute))
        {
            tb.Paper_Time_Minute = PaperDurationMinute;
        }
        string s1;
        s1 = Paper_Subject.SelectedItem.Text;
        var q = from u in db.tbl_Subject where u.Subject_Name.Equals(s1) select u;
        if (q.Count() > 0)
        {
            SubjectId = q.FirstOrDefault().Subject_Id;
            tb.Subject_Id = SubjectId;
        }
        if (int.TryParse(Session["TeacherID"].ToString(), out TeacherId))
        {
            tb.Teacher_Id = TeacherId;
        }
        db.tbl_Paper.Add(tb);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

when button call i want to get the selected value of dropbox but every time i get the first value due to pageload

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you only fill your Dropbox when the page first loads, and when some data is changed. To fill your Dropbox when the page first loads you can use a property `IsPostBack`, which is false only when you load your page for the first time, so the statement `(!IsPostBack)` will return true when you first load the page. Therefore you can do:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(!IsPostBack)
     {
         //code here will be only executed the first time the page is loaded
         var q = from u in db.tbl_Subject select u;
         Paper_Subject.DataSource=q.ToList();
         Paper_Subject.DataTextField = "Subject_Name";
         Paper_Subject.DataValueField = "Subject_Id";
         Paper_Subject.DataBind();

         for (int i = 0; i <= 12;i++)
         {
             if(i<10)
                 Paper_Duration_Hour.Items.Add("0"+i.ToString());
             else
                 Paper_Duration_Hour.Items.Add(i.ToString());
         }
         for (int i = 0; i <= 60; i=i+5)
         {
             if(i<10)
                 Paper_Duration_Minute.Items.Add("0"+i.ToString());
             else
                 Paper_Duration_Minute.Items.Add(i.ToString());
         }
     }
    //code here will be executed every time page loaded
}
```

and the code will only be executed when you first load your page.